# object update in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

I'm new to ORM. Is it possible in ORM framework (let's say hibernate) , to map an object (entity) to a table and get the object to be refresh and update in memory as a result of the table being updated outside of the above object - table relation ?so the object in memory (in cache) is always reflect the table state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic refresh mechanism, but you can refresh any entity instance manually by calling [`Session.flush`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/):

> Re-read the state of the given instance from the underlying database.
>   It is inadvisable to use this to implement long-running sessions that
>   span many business tasks. This method is, however, useful in certain
>   special circumstances. For example
>
> - where a database trigger alters the object state upon insert or update
> - after executing direct SQL (eg. a mass update) in the same session
> - after inserting a Blob or Clob